# questions about kerberos forward and proxy mode

Tags: kerberos, forward

I have a question about forward in Kerberos: 
Does forward mean that the end user will give the TGT to a service so that the service can use the TGT to request others tickets when necessary? If it is the case, does that mean when user first authenticates himself/herself to AS, user will set certain flags, and AS will return user a TGT with FORWARDED set? And then user will give this TGT to service? Is this right? Or asked in other way, if user gives TGT to a service, this FORWARDED TGT is issued by AS or TGS? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first assumption is right. The forwarded TGT should be included in the service ticket which is generated with the help of the AS. Otherwise the client has no chance to verify if the service is really registered. Have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246080%28v=prot.13%29.aspx). It might help you.